# How to catch Spring Security login form before Spring gets it?

Tags: spring-security

I have a Spring login form with username and password, which points to /myapp/j_spring_security_check.

I am hoping to intercept the form submission when someone submits the login form before Spring gets the request.

Basically, I am hoping to to be able to review user input to see if it meets certain requirements. If it does not, the application will take the user back to the login form. If user input meets the requirements, then the flow goes to Spring authentication.

How can I do this? In an efficient way?

Thanks!

Comment: this link might help 

http://tejakantamneni.wordpress.com/2008/08/23/spring-security-using-custom-authentication-processing-filter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using regular Spring Security functionality.  The steps are:

1. Implement a custom [`WebAuthenticationDetailsSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/WebAuthenticationDetailsSource.html) and [`WebAuthenticationDetails`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/WebAuthenticationDetails.html).  The `WebAuthenticationDetails` will capture the extra form fields that you want to validate.

   **Note:** In Spring 3.0 you'll need to [use a BeanPostProcessor to configure](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-namespace-post-processor) the `WebAuthenticationDetailsSource` into the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.   In Spring 3.1 you can do this directly in the `<form-login>` namespace config.
2. Implement a custom `AuthenticationProvider` and in `authenticate()` check the `WebAuthenticationDetails`, throwing a `AuthenticationException` if validation fails.  In your login page check for this exception.

Alternatively, you can create a `Filter` that does your validation and add it before the Spring Security filter.

Comment: ericacm, Thanks so much for your input. My intention was to use something like Filter. When a request reaches the authenticate() method, I have no efficient way of displaying a specific error message just under a field. I can throw an exception from within authenticate(), but that is not specific enough.

Basically, I want to treat the login form as other Spring-MVC from, if there is a validation error, there will be a message displayed just under that field.

I tried Filter approach, but it appears that there is no way for me to put the error message in request scope. 

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: If you use the first method (steps 1 and 2) then you can get the error message in your login page with `((AuthenticationException) session.getAttribute(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION_KEY)).getMessage()`.

Comment: Of course you could do the same thing with the `Filter`, put the exception in the session.

Comment: In my tests, AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION_KEY does not exist in session. Actually, the value of AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION_KEY is SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION, from which I get session message via ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}. However, this message is a general one and there is no elegant way for me to know which field produced the authentication error. Did I miss something? Many thanks!

Comment: The idea is you create a custom subclass of AuthenticationExeception and add whatever data you want in that exception, for example, the field that cause the validation failure.  Then you can get that data when you pull the exception out of the session.

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer above as a guide, this is a working example I created of a post-processor that lets you specify which login form variables to provide to the authenticator, and an example custom authenticator that checks for a terms_of_service checkbox value in the login form.

In the Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="authFormDetailsPostProcessor" class="com.sefaira.authauth.AuthFormDetailsPostProcessor">
  <property name="formVarNames" value="terms_of_service_accepted"/>
</bean>
```

AuthFormDetailsPostProcessor.java:

```
public class AuthFormDetailsPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    private String [] formVarNames;

    public void setFormVarNames (String formVarNames) { 
    this.formVarNames = formVarNames.split (",");
    }

    public static class Details extends WebAuthenticationDetails {

    private Map<String, String> map;

    public Details (HttpServletRequest request, String [] parameters) {
        super (request);

        this.map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (String parameter : parameters) {
        this.map.put (parameter.trim(), request.getParameter (parameter.trim()));
        }
    }

    public String get (String name) {
        return map.get(name);
    }
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String name) {
        if (bean instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter) {
            ((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter)bean).setAuthenticationDetailsSource(
                    new AuthenticationDetailsSource() {
                        public Object buildDetails(Object context) {

                if (formVarNames == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException ("AuthFormDetailsPostProcessor bean requires a formVarNames property, specifying a comma-delimited list of form vars to provide in the details object.");
                }

                return new Details ((HttpServletRequest) context, formVarNames);
                        }
                    });
        }
        return bean;
    }

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String name) {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

This is the custom Authenticator that uses it:

```
public class AuthServiceAuthenticator implements AuthenticationProvider {

   @Override
    public Authentication authenticate (Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    String email = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();  
    String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

    AuthFormDetailsPostProcessor.Details details = (AuthFormDetailsPostProcessor.Details) authentication.getDetails();

    // see if they checked the terms_of_service checkbox        
    String termsOfServiceVar = details.get ("terms_of_service_accepted");
    boolean termsOfServiceAccepted = (termsOfServiceVar != null && termsOfServiceVar.equals ("on"));

        // ... do your custom authentication ...

        return authentication;  // or a new authentication object
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }
}
```