# Spring Security - How to add custom parameter except username/password in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Tags: authentication, spring-security

I am using spring 3 in my app and facing one problem. I have configured spring security like this in my xml file :

```
<bean id="authenticationFilter"     class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
        p:authenticationManager-ref="myAuthenticationManager"
        p:authenticationFailureHandler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        p:authenticationSuccessHandler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        p:sessionAuthenticationStrategy-ref="sas" p:usernameParameter="username"
        p:passwordParameter="password" **p:customparameter="mycustomparameter"** p:filterProcessesUrl="/validate_user.jspx"
        p:postOnly="true" />
```

But after initializing the spring context, I am getting exception that `mycustomparameter` doesn't have any getter/setter and not found and so..

So I need to pass my custom param to my custom authenticatemanager class (where I am getting uname and pwd in authentication object).(I may get this additional info in `authentication.getDetails()`)
Also I have this field in my login.jsp page like -

```
<s:hidden label="Password" id="login_form_mycustomparameter" name="mycustomparameter"
value="false" cssClass="txtbox" required="true" />
```

Is it possible ?
If not, please suggest alternative way to achieve this ?

Thanks..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028532/how-to-catch-spring-security-login-form-before-spring-gets-it/9034851#9034851

Answer (score 0):

The customparameter is attempting to call UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setCustomparameter which does not exist. Therefore you need to create a custom Filter that extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and provides a setCustomparameter method. The custom Filter you create would then need to create a custom Authentication object that contains this custom parameter. Last, you would need a custom AuthenticationProvider that then utilizes the custom parameter when authenticating the user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to `create` custom authentication object ??
 Can you please post some example code ??